# create list with sublists of random length

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to create a list which contains `n` sublists, whereby each sublist has a random length and contains integers from 0 to `m`:

A single results could be for `n=6` and `m=8`:

```
{{1},{6,4},{7,6,3,8},{5,3},{0},{5,0,7,5,2,7}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
n = 6 ; m = 8; lmax = 10;

RandomInteger[{0, m}, #] & /@ RandomInteger[lmax, n] (* or *)
Table[RandomInteger[{0, m}], n, RandomInteger[lmax]] (* or *)
Table[RandomInteger[{0, m}, RandomInteger[lmax]], n] (* or *)
Array[RandomInteger[{0, m}, RandomInteger[lmax]] &, n]
```

> {{7, 0, 6, 6, 3, 1, 4, 4}, {5, 6, 4}, {0, 7, 5, 1, 3, 7, 5, 0, 
>     0}, {}, {1, 2}, {5, 8, 4, 1, 2}}

If you want to disallow empty lists use `{1, lmax}` in place of `lmax` above, e.g,

```
RandomInteger[{0, m}, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, lmax}, n]
```

> {{7, 1, 7, 0, 1, 1, 4, 4}, {6, 5, 5, 0, 8, 1}, {6, 1, 8, 3, 6, 5, 0, 
>     8, 2}, {7, 6}, {7, 5, 1, 8, 7, 5, 5, 8}, {0, 5}}

Comment: Thank you for the solutions.

Comment: @lio, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.